# Reality check - Forest in space city

Tags: science-fiction, space-colonization, space-constructs

How could you create a forest in a space city, like the Citadel of the *Mass Effect* game? Would this forest provide renewal of oxygen for the population?

Is it "simple" to create an atmosphere and airflow to ventilate the entire city? What are the requirements for growing the forest and ventilating the entire city? The city has about 1 million people.

Does it take much technological advancement from the present for this?

Comment: "airflow to fuel the entire city" - probably you meant something else then "fuel", ventilate maybe ? What you mean by requirements - requirements for airflows, requirements for growing the forest, requirements to build such city with forest and airflows? How big is the city(size, people or anything)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I mean ventilate.

Comment: And about the requeriments, i mean the requeriments for growing the forest,AND vantilate in entire city. The city has about 1 million people.

Comment: you can edit you own answer, such action are welcome here as long as they clarify the question, and will make the job to answer the question easier by eliminating the need to read all the comments(not a lot of them now, but in general)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Lonely Forest

The hardest part of the construction is the biosphere creation, hardest in terms of answering the question - how far are we from being capable of building such city. It is not hard in terms of actual doing, it is hard in terms of the knowledge we need to do so.

A forest can't grow alone, just as a plain set of trees.
To allow access of humans to those trees it needs to create some kind of microbiological system which is robust to possible microbiological outsiders. Some small creatures which form robust system to protect the system from possible small creatures outsiders and who manage microbiological compnents of the system(like worm do, and not only they). Might be even birds and animals to control parts of the system - insects, worms, etc.

There have to be a stable system of [Primary producers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_producers) and [Consumer's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_(food_chain))

If it will be too big(quantity of components), it will be hard to model the behavior, to monitor the changes, to notice new components (invasion, mutations), to control the system in a meaningful way(modify it).
Too few components and the system will be not robust (high fluctuation of producents and consumers (back and forth in quantities for both of them) as an example of such situation are rabbits, rats in Australia. [Rabbits in Australia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbits_in_Australia)).

Such problems can be incorporated into the design of the system and result might be hard to compensate. If do not care about the problem then strict Australian rules about biological control will be easy cheesy compared to the rules which the city might need to protect its forest ecosystem.

Also, interesting story to read is [Biosphere 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biosphere_2) experiment and the types of problems they had (They got the negative results.)

It has to be remembered that a human has symbiotic relations with over then 3000 species of microbiological life(I mean guts microflora mostly, but there is more than only guts microflora). And the funniest part about microbiological life is it very very much like to mutate. And mutations are the process which made a human from a single cell organism. And it will not take a lot of time to mutate from [E. coli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escherichia_coli) into something which considers the forest as the food substrate - in the ideal case of course when there is a sterile forest waiting for adventures of E. coli.

Eliminating the human access to the forest almost eliminates the need to have it. So the problem of creating the ecosystem is a real key problem for the city. There is a lot to say, very exciting set of problems - how to exchange flora and fauna with other cities, how to control everything, how to ensure all humans have similar immunity, fighting diseases, biological control on all levels, all those procedures sweet sweet Grail of biological questions which are so interesting to solve and which will never end.

## The rest

Compared to creating the biological system which is suitable for the city everything else is fairly simple.

At the moment we probably have all necessary technologies to do such a city, and the main thing which stops us from being capable of doing so is the absence of easy access to space and absence of manufacturing capabilities in space.

As for the construction interesting work to read [O'Neill, G. K: The Colonization of Space, Physics Today, vol. 27, no. 9, Sept. 1974, pp. 32-40.](http://www.nss.org/settlement/physicstoday.htm) it does not look that complex after all.

Also interesting material here at nasa site about possible settlements and their requirements and different considerations https://settlement.arc.nasa.gov/75SummerStudy/Table_of_Contents1.html

## more about your questions particularly

Yes, a forest can produce enough oxygen, same way as any plant. How much is it needed per human - the need is about the same amount of square meters as for other plants, 100-200 m<sup>2</sup> should be close enough to be sufficient(more if there more consuments, not only humans) - in average 1000m<sup>2</sup> should be more than enough in most possible cases.

Yes, it is simply to create the atmospheres (whatever it means) and ventilate the city. The city is artificial construction, it contains nothing which was formed by nature and entirely is a product of human activity. Ventilation systems are part of the construction, by design, but as construction, they are a subset of much bigger construction.
In the O'Neil project, natural convection created by warm-cold air will work. There can be different solutions and they might depend on the implementation of the city, but in general it is not that of a big deal.

But with big open spaces heating the surface and might be cooling some high spots will be enough to create sufficient air flow and possible even winds. Basically creating a draft, not need in moving parts or big fans, just heating and cooling, the same way as chimney stuff works.

Key problems so far are biology and access to space. Acces to space the problem will be probably solved by SpaceX, biology is what is left.

Comment: In space, it's better to think in terms of cubic meters or kg - and square meter of forest takes up a LOT more of both volume and mass than grass, hydroponics etc. Also, oxygen is not created. It's released from carbon dioxide, and this process removes both carbon and water from the loop (carbohydrates). If you don't provide any way to recirculate them back, your system will not be sustainable.

Comment: @Mołot Why is it better? Yes, a forest is less mass efficient, especially at more mature state, than grass in terms of producing converting CO2, but OP wanna the forest, it is doable and no problems here and it is excellent for recreation purposes as you mention in your answer. There are countless ways to return biomass into water + CO2  etc state, biodegradation, feed to livestock, use as compost, use as a substrate for mushrooms, etc. Just burn it at the end.  You need to remove about 4 tons per hectare of wood to keep the forest at a particular level. Oxygen is not created - yes, I know.

Comment: Air pumps are rated by volume, their energy consumption increases with volume. And no, you do not want biomass to turn to water and CO2 directly. If you would do this, net effect on atmosphere is exactly NULL. You need carbohydrates back in the loop, and turning wood into food is in no way an easy task.

Comment: @Mołot Do we agree that humans need food, and food production is out of the scope of OP's question? There are ways to connect those 2 loops - with insects, worms, livestock, and agrocultures - with food production loop. Other than that, yes, your point valid. Converting wood into food an easy task, it just not that fast but pretty easy. Will add information about that tomorrow(but it is more biology chemistry stuff, do OP really need it?). How are air-pump specific to Space, what makes them so special for space that it defines in which terms we should think in space?

Comment: Food production can't be out of scope if we talk about collecting CO2 from atmosphere. Carbon needs to go in the loop: Food -> Human -> Carbon Dioxide -> Something -> Food if you do not want to need constant supplies of food or atmosphere. And if you do need them, production of oxygen starts to be irrelevant as you either bring it anyway, or bring even heavier stuff.

Answer (score 9):

> Does it take much technological advancement from the current for this?

Yes. A lot. But not due to forest  thing. We simply need to get to the "space cities" state  of  technological advancement,  and we are not  even close.

## Why to make a forest?

Certainly **not** to scrub CO<sub>2</sub>. You  would need to somehow  remove created  biomass from the forest  to keep the balance. It is much easier done with hydroponic crops, where you can get CO<sub>2</sub> removed, O<sub>2</sub> released, and plant matter can be used as food. Forest's meaning would be negligible compared  to hydroponics.

So why? There are many valid reasons:

1. **Psychological effect.** Possibility to sit in nature-like environment, where you do not see artificial walls  because trees obscure them,  and don't see ceiling because in woods you rarely see sky anyway, can be a great relief on long missions.
2. **Habitat for endangered species.** Especially for  small birds and animals. This is really good for PR,  and good  PR helps with getting money  to build your station, and keep  it running.
3. **Space tourism.** First forest  outside Mother Earth! See trees that grew with artificial gravity, what fantastic shapes they made! Again, funding.
4. **Biological experiments** - Who knows how lack of gravity, or your kind of artificial gravity, would affect trees? For sure I don't.

## How to make it happen?

You need to read about the roots of trees you want to have in your forest. I think [this page](http://www.hellistreeconsultants.co.uk/kbi1000014_tree_root_systems.html) is one of decent starting points.

[image: Root system]

You need to make sure you have enough of soil for roots, and walls / floors strong enough for roots not to penetrate them. This is a lot of mass, and mass is expense when we talk about space exploration. For now, it's expensive. Can't find reliable sources, but it's above $10,000 per kg, as far as I remember.

You also need a way to provide water and fertilizers. This would be quite a big engineering task. Maybe you can just spray it? Don't know how it would work with your kind of artificial gravity. In microgravity, it simply wouldn't work properly, and you need to engineer up some other way of getting soil moist.

Comment: Damn, much better than my half-written answer.

Comment: @StigHemmer by all means, finish your answer and post it, too!  Probably you got a point or two I haven't figured out.

Comment: @StigHemmer post, this answer isn't that great, too much focus on the price and such, not answers the question about implementation of the growth etc. Reasons to do so are good(OP haven't asked for them btw), the link is useful, second half of the answer isn't that good.

Comment: @MolbOrg OP asked about requirements, so I wrote about them - forest would require soil, water and fertilizer. For the growth, we don't know what kind of artificial gravity he is using, so I pointed it out, and the rest is covered. Reasons are there to answer part about atmosphere (problem with slow work and lack of way to put carbon back into circulation) - he did ask about atmosphere all right.

Comment: I think that was a very helpful answer. Maybe I did not ask the right question, but it helps me a lot.

Comment: @thierseuller Glad it was useful. And I hope you will get another answers, covering the points I didn't :) I'll be glad to upvote them.

Comment: Don't forget the forest needs energy from light as well.

Comment: Adding to your list of _why_ from the movie [Silent Running](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0067756/): We've ruined the climate on Earth, important plants are kept in space for possible reintroduction after cleaning up the planet.

Comment: The super cost for the mass comes from getting mass out of Earth's gravity well. Grab the mass from the asteroid belt or the moon, and you can get it for much cheaper. Alternately, when we get to this stage, the energy cost for a rocket (or space elevator) might be much cheaper.

Comment: Fun fact to add, during the Biosphere 2 experiment they found out trees that grow in environments without wind are prone to fall over for no reason.